# When running tests with cypress got error "Uncaught TypeErrror: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"

Tags: cypress

I am new to Cypress and trying to test a Ruby on Rails web application, using stand alone Cypress.

Here is test code

```
/// <reference types="cypress" />

context('Login', () => {


  it('cy.title() - get the title', () => {
    cy.visit('https://apps.novabadmintonclub.com')
    cy.title().should('include', 'Northern Virginia Badminton Club')
    cy.get(':nth-child(2) > .nav-link').click()
    cy.get("#user_email").type("john.doe@gmail.com")
    cy.get("#user_password").type("xx")
    cy.get('.actions > input').click()

  })
})
```

The test fails with the error "Uncaught TypeErrror: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"

I am using latest version 4.3.0 of Cypress on OSX.

If I change the visit url directly to sign in page `https://apps.novabadmintonclub.com/users/sign_in`, it works fine.

So looks like either the whole dom is not rendered before `type` starts to add text or something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was indeed an application code error. I had javascript code `document.getElementById('clock').innerHTML` looking for a dom ID which was not there, hence the error. After I added a null check for that dom ID, Cypress test worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

Using the following code I have got this to work.

Also using latest cypress version, please make sure you're closing your statements as well. 
Also I didn't do it but i'd always recommend doing assertions after you get statements so asserting the values you've entered actually exist.

```
describe('stack overflow test', () => {
it('should navigate and attempt to login to badminton club', () => {
    cy.visit('https://apps.novabadmintonclub.com');
    cy.get(':nth-child(2) > .nav-link').click({force: true});
    cy.get('#user_email').type('john.doe@gmail.com');
    cy.get('#user_password').type('xx');
    cy.get('.actions > input').click();
});
```

});

Here is a screenshot of the cypress GUI to prove it pops up with the error message.

[image]

Comment: Sorry I did not work for me. Same issue as shown below.

![screenshot] (https://imgur.com/a/k2YoQFQ)

Comment: Unfortunately I can not reproduce this. Can you provide browser version and how you're running the tests?

Comment: I am running cypress using this command: `./node_modules/.bin/cypress open` and as per cypress console app, chrome version is 80

Comment: Interesting, yeah with my code block above I can't reproduce at all.

Comment: Have you tried putting a wait in after the nav click? Couple of seconds?

Comment: I tried adding a wait of 5 seconds and it did not help. Rails does make an XHR request when Login link is clicked. I saw something in Cypress git issues (https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/6537) which might be relevant, but I am not sure. But that does not answer why it works for you. What is your chrome version?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211089/discussion-between-navjeet-and-mvoase).